# Limit secondary y-axis labels to 3 significant figures when primary y-axis is in log-scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a variable dataset and a guideline that far exceeds the bulk of the data values. Also need to present results in two different units, with primary y in pCi/kg and secondary y in SI units of Bq/kg.

```
mydata <- structure(list(result = c(27.59, 4.51, 11.2, 66.5, 4.38, 5.097, 
                        14.4, 3.5, 4.3, 10.5, 3.008, 6.43, 20, 1.2, 4.8, 2, 3.7, 4.5, 
                        6.4, 3.2, 3.3, 1.9, 3.3, 3.3, 4.5, 1.1, 5, 1.9, 0.6, 3.9, 2.8, 
                        0.5, 4, 5.2, 2.3, 2.8, 5.3, 3.4, 4.1, 1.2, 9.4, 2.4, 6.4, 5.7, 
                        2.2, 1.8, 4, 3.9, 4.2, 4.6, 3.2, 3.4, 3, 2.4, 1.93, 8.49, 1.24, 
                        1.37, 1.23, 1.05, 0.362, 1.22, 0.648, 1.59, 0.992, 1.45, 1.68, 
                        1.04, 0.84, 1.44, 0.796, 2.08, 2.77, 0.653, 1.42, 1.56, 1.29, 
                        14.4, 1.82, 7.81, 0.584, 1.07, 1.1, 0.639, 1.12, 2.76, 6.57, 
                        3.08, 1.99, 1.68, 2.76, 0.708, 4.28, 2.58, 1.32, 257, 2.58, 7.8, 
                        1.13, 3.78, 0.634, 0.433, 0.887, 0.96), event = structure(c(1L, 
                        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("event1", "event2", "event3"),
                        class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -104L), class = "data.frame")
 library(tidyverse)
 library(scales)

 # Initial linear scale run
 ggplot(mydata, aes(x=event, y=result)) +
 scale_y_continuous(sec.axis=sec_axis(~.*0.037, name = "Bq/kg")) +
 geom_boxplot() +
 geom_point() +
 labs(y="Result (pCi/kg)") +
 geom_hline(yintercept=545) #guideline

 # Log transform
 
 base_breaks <- function(n = 10){
 function(x) {
 axisTicks(log10(range(x, na.rm = TRUE)), log = TRUE, n = n)
  }
 }

 ggplot(mydata, aes(x=event, y=result)) +
 scale_y_continuous(trans = log_trans(), breaks = base_breaks(), labels = prettyNum, 
 sec.axis=sec_axis(~.*0.037, name = "Bq/kg")) + #ugly sec-y
 geom_boxplot() +
 geom_point() +
 labs(y="Result (pCi/kg)") +
 geom_hline(yintercept=545)
```

The initial linear scale plot is not interpretable but yields desired formatting on the secondary y-axis. The log-transformed plot shows all data but secondary axis labels badly formatted. Is there a way to reformat the sec axis such that only 3 sig figs? AND ideally achieve better resolution on the breaks (e.g., 0.1, 0.2, 1, etc.)? Numerous searches on this have not yielded a solution that works without overriding scaling of the primary y-axis.

Comment: You could set the breaks and labels via `sec_axis(..., breaks = c(.05, .1, .2, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20), labels = scales::label_number(accuracy = .001)))`

Comment: Does `scale_y_continuous(trans = log_trans(), breaks = base_breaks(), labels = prettyNum,  sec.axis=sec_axis(~.*0.037, breaks = base_breaks(), scales::comma_format(accuracy = 0.01),  name = "Bq/kg"))` do approx what you want?